# Unable to make multiple integrations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to make these multiple integrations, but I face many errors that I do not know the way to avoid them.

```
Integrate[1/(x - y)^3*Exp[I*10^6*(x - y)]-(I*10^6)/(x -y)^2* Exp[I*10^6*(x - y)], {x, 50*10^-9, 55*10^-9}, {y, 50*10^-9, 45*10^-9}]
```

Comment: Are the errors about your integral not being convergent ?

Comment: Please always include the error in the question, and address it. In this case, it says that the integral does not converge. What do you mean by "avoiding them"?  Do you believe that the integral is convergent after all?  Prove it then.  Is this a question about integration in general (why it's divergent) and not about Mathematica?  In that case it is off topic here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I recognized the problem with me..

Answer (score 1):

The integral diverges when z = x-y goes to zero at x ==y == 50*10^-9 as 1/z^3. Principal value does'nt help.

Insert a parameter a for the boundary of x. You get solutions (too long to show here) for all a except for a == 50.

```
int[a_] = 
   Integrate[
     1/(x - y)^3*Exp[I*10^6*(x - y)] - (I*10^6)/(x - y)^2*
     Exp[I*10^6*(x - y)], {x, a*10^-9, 55*10^-9}, {y, 50*10^-9, 
     45*10^-9}, Assumptions -> 50 < a < 55]  

Limit[int[a], a -> 50, Direction -> -1]

(*     -Infinity     *)
```

Comment: See my comment at the answer below.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I removed the post.